# When I run the dev server, I got an error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined' in external "url"

Tags: webpack-4

I have just started to study Webpack and trying to setup development environment based on Webpack4.

I put one script for executing dev server in `package.json` like below.

# **package.json**

```
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    }
```

However, there was an error message like below when I execute`'npm run dev'` on my terminal.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\webpack-setup\node_modules\destroy'
 @ ./node_modules/destroy/index.js 14:17-30
```

So, I installed `'webpack-node-externals'` and put configuration in `'webpack.config.js'` like below.

# **install webpack-node-externals module**

```
    # npm install --save-dev webpack-node-externals
```

# **webpack.config.js**

```
    const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

    module.exports = {
        target: 'web',
        externals: [nodeExternals()],
        devServer: {
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 3000,
            open: true
        }
    };
```

When a browser was opened, there was an error on a browser like below.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at eval (external_"url":1)
    at Object.url (main.js:289)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:20)
    at Object.eval (webpack:///(:3000/webpack)-dev-server/client?:6:11)
    at eval (webpack:///(:3000/webpack)-dev-server/client?:249:30)
    at Object../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://localhost:3000 (main.js:97)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:20)
    at eval (webpack:///multi_(:3000/webpack)-dev-server/client?:1:1)
    at Object.0 (main.js:190)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:20)
```

I'm not sure this error is related to `'webpack-node-externals'` module or not,
but could I get some guide for solving this situation?

Comment: Can you provide a cloned repo. Also, did you install your node modules  prior to running dev server? You want to do    `yarn install` or `npm install` prior to running the dev server.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Artimus

I put my sources on my github.
Here is a repository URL.

git@github.com:hapumee/react16-webpack4-express-babel7-setup.git

Comment: Also, I Installed modules through npm like below.

### Webpack modules
# npm install --save-dev webpack webpack-cli clean-webpack-plugin html-webpack-plugin webpack-dev-server

### Express module
# npm install --save express

### Babel modules
# npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/node babel-loader
# React modules
# npm install --save react react-dom @babel/preset-react

### Node modules
# npm install --save-dev nodemon
# npm install --save-dev webpack-node-externals

Comment: So does this work or do you still need help? Did fixing the typo help?

Comment: I still have the same problem to load a web page on localhost:3000 even through I fixed the typo in webpack.config.js

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem in your config file. I ran a sample with this and it worked:

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')
module.exports = {
  target: 'web',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  devServer: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000,
    open: true,
  },
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Ali Doustkani.

I looked at my `webpack.config.js` again, and found there was a typo on my post. ^^;;; I edited my post. Thank you so much!